# PIG creates file on Hadoop but cannot write to it

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am learning hadoop and created a simple pig script.
Reading a file works, but writing to another file does not.
My script runs fine, the `DUMP f` command shows me 10 records, as expected. But when I store the same relation to a file (`store f into 'result.csv';`), there are some odd messages on the console, and for some reason, in the end I have a result file with only the first 3 records.

My questions are:

- What's the matter with the IOException, when reading worked and
  writing worked at least partly?
- Why does the console tell me `Total records written : 0`, when actually 3 records have been written?
- Why didn't it store the 10 records, as expected?

My Script (it's just some sandbox playing)

```
cd /user/samples

c = load 'crimes.csv' using PigStorage(',')
as (ID:int,Case_Number:int,Date:chararray,Block:chararray,IUCR:chararray,Primary_Type,Description,LocationDescription,Arrest:boolean,Domestic,Beat,District,Ward,CommunityArea,FBICode,XCoordinate,YCoordinate,Year,UpdatedOn,Latitude,Longitude,Location);

c = LIMIT c 1000;

t = foreach c generate ID, Date, Arrest, Year;

f = FILTER t by Arrest==true;
f = LIMIT f 10;
dump f;
store f into 'result.csv';
```

part of the console output:

```
2016-07-21 15:55:07,435 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-07-21 15:55:07,537 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRJobStats - Unable to get job counters
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From m1.hdp2/192.168.178.201 to 0.0.0.0:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.getCounters(HadoopShims.java:132)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRJobStats.addCounters(MRJobStats.java:284)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil.addSuccessJobStats(MRPigStatsUtil.java:235)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil.accumulateStats(MRPigStatsUtil.java:165)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:360)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:308)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1474)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1459)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1448)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.access$500(PigServer.java:118)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1773)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:707)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1075)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:505)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:231)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:206)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:564)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From m1.hdp2/192.168.178.201 to 0.0.0.0:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getJobStatus(ClientServiceDelegate.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getJobStatus(YARNRunner.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getJob(Cluster.java:184)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.getCounters(HadoopShims.java:126)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call From m1.hdp2/192.168.178.201 to 0.0.0.0:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor18.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.getJobReport(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.impl.pb.client.MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getJobReport(MRClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:324)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
    ... 36 more
2016-07-21 15:55:07,540 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2016-07-21 15:55:07,571 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.7.2   0.16.0  hadoop  2016-07-21 15:50:17 2016-07-21 15:55:07 FILTER,LIMIT

Success!

Job Stats (time in seconds):
JobId   Maps    Reduces MaxMapTime  MinMapTime  AvgMapTime  MedianMapTime   MaxReduceTime   MinReduceTime   AvgReduceTime   MedianReducetime    Alias   Feature Outputs
job_1469130571595_0001  3   1   n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a c       
job_1469130571595_0002  1   1   n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a n/a c,f,t       hdfs://localhost:9000/user/samples/result.csv,

Input(s):
Successfully read 0 records from: "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/samples/crimes.csv"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/samples/result.csv"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1469130571595_0001  ->  job_1469130571595_0002,
job_1469130571595_0002


2016-07-21 15:55:07,573 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2016-07-21 15:55:07,585 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2016-07-21 15:55:08,592 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Comment: What is output of  `jps` command?

Comment: Have you checked the link that stack trace suggests?
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused